# Pasar valor de select HTML a PHP con ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

```
(ESTO ESTÁ EN UN SCRIPT APARTE EN WORDPRESS, QUE LO RECONOCE PERO GENERA ERROR)

(function($){
var d= document.getElementById("lista").value;
$.post(document.location.pathname , { variable: d } );
```

}(jQuery))

```
<div>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
  (AQUI SE RECIBE EL VALUE DEL SELECT)
  <div>
    Seleccione periodo: 
    <select onchange="test()" name="name" id="lista">
        <option value="0" selected>Haga clic aquí</option>
        <option value="1" <?php if($_POST['name']=='1') echo 'selected="selected" ';?>> ENERO</option>
        <option value="2"  <?php if($_POST['name']=='2') echo 'selected="selected" ';?>>FEBRERO</option>
        <option value="3"  <?php if($_POST['name']=='3') echo 'selected="selected" ';?>>MARZO</option>
        <option value="4"  <?php if($_POST['name']=='4') echo 'selected="selected" ';?>>ABRIL</option>
        <option value="5"  <?php if($_POST['name']=='5') echo 'selected="selected" ';?>>MAYO</option>
        <option value="6"  <?php if($_POST['name']=='6') echo 'selected="selected" ';?>>JUNIO</option>
        <option value="7"  <?php if($_POST['name']=='7') echo 'selected="selected" ';?>>JULIO</option>
        <option value="8"  <?php if($_POST['name']=='8') echo 'selected="selected" ';?>>AGOSTO</option>
        <option value="9"  <?php if($_POST['name']=='9') echo 'selected="selected" ';?>>SEPTIEMBRE</option>
        <option value="10"  <?php if($_POST['name']=='10') echo 'selected="selected" ';?>>OCTUBRE</option>
        <option value="11"  <?php if($_POST['name']=='11') echo 'selected="selected" ';?>>NOVIEMBRE</option>
        <option value="12"  <?php if($_POST['name']=='12') echo 'selected="selected" ';?>>DICIEMBRE</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Consultar">
    <input type="button" onclick=" generateexcel('testTable') " value="Exportar a Excel">
  </div>
</form>
</div>

<?php
(AQUÍ DEBERÍA LLEGAR EL VALOR O LA VARIABLE DESDE AJAXXX)
if(isset($_POST['d']))
{  
  $name = $_POST['d'];
}
echo "No encontrado";
?>
```

Lo que quiero hacer es tomar el value del `select` y pasarlo a `PHP` mediante `ajax`.

Error que muestra en el navegador:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: esta pregunta ya la habías formulado antes, no?

Comment: La había formulado de otra forma, dado que en la anterior pregunta era con POST solamente, en este caso necesito que sea con ajax para que sea dinámico el envio de la variable. La verdad no se programar en ajax ni en javascript y necesito la ayuda.

Comment: estaba probando tu código y me pregunto para qué está hecho que quieres hacer con eso si me puedes decir te puedo ayudar

Comment: el código selecciona un mes de un select en html y toma el value del select, en este caso un número (1 para enero, 2 para febrero y asi) y con este valor se hace una consulta en sql, pero por ahora sólo necesito que capture el valor del select de HTML y lo pase a la variable PHP por medio de ajax

Comment: ok ok tu quieres hacer un form para cambiar los meses a tiempo real mira aqui te dejo esto espero que ayude http://download.jqueryajaxphp.com/firewall/data/liveselectedit.zip

Comment: Lo único que quiero hacer es tomar el value del select y pasarlo a php mediante ajax

Comment: Tu fallo esta en la forma de llamar al select. En el código el ID es lista, y en javascript le llamas name

Answer (score 3):

Hay varias cosillas que pueden mejorar en tu código. Vamos a ello:

Veo que quieres usar el $.post para eso necesitas jQuery, ese error que tienes que 'post' of undefined, significa que el $ ó jQuery no esta definido. Recuerda que siempre debes agregar el link al jQuery:

```
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js
```

También para agregar eventos al DOM debes asegurarte que el documento esta listo, puedes utilizar:

```
$('body').ready
```

Lo que este adentro de este .ready se va a ejectuar cuando el body este listo. Aunque aun no termine de cargar todo.
o

```
$(window).load
```

Lo que este adentro del .load se va a ejecutar cuando el window haya cargado, es decir que puede que ya este listo el DOM pero aun hay imagenes cargando, esto se ejecuta hasta que todo termina.

---

Ahora para que tu código se vea mas limpio yo haría una función en js para seleccionar una opción del select. Algo parecido a:

```
function selectOption (value_to_select) {
 $('#select-id').val(value_to_select);
}
```

De esta forma harías:

```
$('body').ready(function () {
  var option_to_select = 2;

  selectOption(option_to_select);
});
```

Y ahora cuando el DOM cargue ya tendrás seleccionada la opción que quieres sin mezclar tanto el php con el html.

---

Ahora para enviar los datos al server, puedes hacer varias cosas, la mas fácil es escuchar el evento "submit" del form y ejecutar el $.ajax, ya que si tienes campos require o de tipo email, la validación por parte del navegador se va a hacer antes de lanzar el "submit". Sería algo así:

```
$('#form-id').on('submit', function () {
  var valueToSend = $('#select-id').val();
  $.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'myPage.php',
    data: {
       myVal: valueToSend
    },
    success: function (data) {
       console.log('Success: ' + data); // Este callback se lanza cuando la url 'myPage' responde con status 200.
    },
    error: function (data) {
       console.log('Error: ' + data); // Este callback que se lanzara si la url 'myPage.php' responde con status de error, e.g. 400, 404, 500, etc...
    }
  });
});
```

Con esto se lanza una llamada $.ajax a la pagina 'myPage.php', en ese parámetro pondrás la pagina a donde quieres mandar la petición. Te dejo la documentación: 
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Y para agarrar el valor con PHP lo cachas con la variable $_POST:

```
$_POST['myVal']; // OJO: cuando lo mandas en el data, se cacha con el nombre que le diste al parámetro: myVal: valueToSend.
```

Comment: Se me olvido mencionar el .on('submit') también va dentro del $('body').ready()

Answer (score 0):

Con JQuery seria algo asi:

```
var value = $("#lista").val();

$.ajax({
  url:'consulta.php?value='+value ,
  method: 'post',
  data: {},

});
```

Comment: Gracias @Cig, creo que eso puede servir, pero en php cómo recibe? <?php $mes = $_POST['name']; ?> o <?php $mes = $_POST; ?>

Comment: Se recibe $mes = $_POST['name'];

Comment: Este código envía `value` por `GET`, es decir, `$_GET['value']`; No envía nada por `POST`.

Answer (score -1):

```
 $(function(){
    $("#lista[name='name']").change(function () {
       var tu_variable_seleccionada = $(this).val();
       $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         //Se omite la url por que es la misma página
         //url: "tu_url",
         //Variable envíada por ajax que recibe php
         data: {selected: tu_variable_seleccionada},
         success: function(data) {
           // Si todo sale bien, puedes agregar algo
         },
         error: function(data) {
           // Si fue error, recibes el error 
         }
    });
   });
  });
```

Comment: Les agradezco los aportes pero quisiera aclarar que es a la misma página, en ese caso no aplica indicar una url. Igualmente no sé cómo se recibiría la variable en php.

Comment: @reymagnus modifique mi respuesta

Comment: Esta forma no funciona en Wordpress:

    function test() {
    d = document.getElementById("lista").value;
    $.post( , { variable: d } );
    }

Ni tampoco esta: 

    function test() {
    d = document.getElementById("lista").value;
    jQuery.post( "", { variable: d } );
    }

Incluyendo en functions.php

    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

Comment: En este caso tu estarías recibiendo la variable `selected`, quedaría así `<?php $mes = $_POST['selected']; ?>`

Comment: No reconoce la función de ajax en Wordpress, genera error en el navegador desde $(function(){  no se si esto debe ir dentro de otra función o hay que incluir ajax de alguna otra forma, aunque jQuery si lo toma en Wordpress y está predefinido el que viene con el tema.   Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function

Comment: function test(){
 
        d = document.getElementById("lista").value;
        $.post( window.location,  d  );
    } arroja un Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined Even JQuery included

Comment: También estoy probando con:     (ESTO ESTÁ EN UN SCRIPT APARTE EN WORDPRESS, QUE LO RECONOCE PERO GENERA ERROR)

    (function($){
    var d= document.getElementById("lista").value;
    $.post(document.location.pathname , { variable: d } );
}(jQuery)) pero me genera este error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

Comment: `$(function(){`lo puedes sustituir por `$(document).ready`

Comment: Me genera un error de unexpected token porque no reconoce $(document).ready{

Comment: https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/adding-jquery-scripts-wordpress/ Revisa esta documentación dice que dependiendo donde  pongas el script es la declaración del JQUERY

Comment: Ahora aparece que test no está definido: Uncaught ReferenceError: test is not defined  se supone que a esa función la debo llamar desde el form, no <form id="formoid" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" onsubmit="test()" >

Comment: Para empezar como es a la misma pagina el action no deberia de ir, en segundo como lo tienes en una función, quita todo lo de `$(document).ready` o `$function` que tengas.

Comment: pero en la página que me pasaste está como lo deje: jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
    var d= document.getElementById("lista").value;
    $.post(document.location.pathname , { variable: d } );
});  sería asi?? test( ){
    var d= document.getElementById("lista").value;
    jQuery.post(document.location.pathname , { variable: d } );
}     Porque así aparece el error de unexpected token

Comment: Persiste el error 404 path not found. No entiendo por qué no puede hacer el post en la misma página.

Comment: Revisa esta liga https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/using-ajax-with-wordpress/

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#cbo_cargos").change(function(){
   cargoValue=$(this).val();
});
```

Comment: ¿Podrías [edit] tu respuesta para agregar una descripción, al menos breve de cómo es que esto soluciona a la pregunta? Más info en [answer]